# tengo un problema con mi aplicación de electron con react typescript, compilado con webpack :(

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, webpack, electron

el problema que tengo es que no puedo usar el ipcrender de electron, en un componente de react hook.
[image: error de react usando el preload]

aqui esta, tanto la configuracion de electron y el preload

```
import {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog} from "electron"
import * as path from "path"

let windowsDesktop: Electron.BrowserWindow | any
function mainWindow(): void {
    windowsDesktop = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 450,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "./preload.ts"),
        },
        titleBarStyle: "hidden",
        titleBarOverlay: {
            symbolColor: "#000",
            color: "#fff",
        },
    })
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
        windowsDesktop.loadURL("http://localhost:8080/")
    } else {
        windowsDesktop.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "./index.html"))
    }
}
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    mainWindow()
})
ipcMain.on("test-invoke", (args: any) => {
    console.log("hello")
})
```

aqui el preload, no me permite comunicarme desde react a electron ya intente de todo y no me

```
import {ipcRenderer, contextBridge} from "electron"

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
    getInfo: (args: any) => ipcRenderer.invoke("test-invoke", args),
})
```

[image: configuración de webpack]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si el problema era webpack y era poner en el target electron-preload para que funcionara y poner js a preload en vez de ts en el path

Comment: Hola dylan, me alegra que encontraras una solución. Te comento que esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, edítala para añadir algo más de detalle (por ejemplo, ¿cómo quedó al final el código de la configuración de webpack?). Lee [answer] para más información.